# pybind11 type as function parameters in library yielding compile error in application linking against that library

Tags: c++, cmake, pybind11

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but in any case, here's what I'm seeing:

Lets say I have a library that's defined something like this:

```
# minimal-lib/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(minimallib
    LANGUAGES CXX
    VERSION 1.0.0
    DESCRIPTION "minimal library")
include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CPP_COMPILER clang++-13)

# get rid of the pybind11 warning spam
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-Wno-attributes HAVE_ATTRIBUTES)
if (HAVE_ATTRIBUTES)
    add_compile_options(-Wno-attributes)
endif()


IF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/experiment CACHE PATH "comment" FORCE)
ENDIF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)

set(
    PSOURCES
        src/fun.cpp
)
set(
    PHEADERS
        include/fun.hpp
)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
    ${PSOURCES}
    ${PHEADERS}
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION 1.0.0
        SOVERSION 1.0.0
        LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG"
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        PRIVATE src)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC pybind11::embed)

install(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
install(
    DIRECTORY include/
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
export(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
)
install(
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake"
)
```

```
//minimal-lib/include/fun.hpp

#ifndef FUN_HPP
#define FUN_HPP

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <optional>
#include <string>

namespace minimallib
{
void write(
        const std::optional<std::string> &file, 
        const pybind11::args &args = pybind11::none(), 
        const pybind11::kwargs &kwargs = pybind11::none());
}//namespace minimallib
#endif //FUN_HPP
```

```
//minimal-lib/src/fun.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "fun.hpp"

void minimallib::write(
        const std::optional<std::string> &file, 
        const pybind11::args &args, 
        const pybind11::kwargs &kwargs)
{
    std::cout << "I should do something more useful." << std::endl;
}
```

and an application project that uses that library that looks something like this:

```
# rms/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)

project(minimalapp
    LANGUAGES CXX
    VERSION 1.0.0)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
IF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
  SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/experiment CACHE PATH "comment" FORCE)
ENDIF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/experiment/")

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
find_package(minimallib REQUIRED)

set(
    PSOURCES
        src/main.cpp
)

set(
    MAIN_HEADERS

)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PHEADERS}
    ${PSOURCES}
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION 1.0.0
        MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "DEBUG")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE pybind11::embed)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE minimallib)


install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

```
#include <minimallib/fun.hpp>

int main()
{
    minimallib::write("foobar.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

The library compiles and links without complaints.
In any case, linking the application using that library fails with an error like this:

```
FAILED: minimalapp-1.0.0 
: && /usr/bin/c++   CMakeFiles/minimalapp.dir/src/main.cpp.o -o minimalapp-1.0.0  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/experiment/lib:  /opt/experiment/lib/libminimallib.so.1.0.0  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/minimalapp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `minimallib::write(std::optional<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&, pybind11::args const&, pybind11::kwargs const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

If I remove the pybind11::kwargs and pybind11::args from the signature in the function in the library, the application that uses it compiles without issue.

I'm somewhat ignorant to looking at the symbols included in the *.so file, but I took a look anyway and here's what I observed.
Case 1) pybind11::args and pybind11::kwargs included in signature: can see the relevant symbol with objdump -t but not with objdump -T.

```
0000000000006259 l     F .text  0000000000000046              _ZN10minimallib5writeERKSt8optionalINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEERKN8pybind114argsERKNSA_6kwargsE
```

Case 2) not including those: can see the relevant symbol with both objdump -t and objdump -T. I note that it's also marked (g)lobal instead of (l)ocal, and marked (D)ynamic instead of ( )normal

```
0000000000006259 g    DF .text  000000000000003e  Base        _ZN10minimallib5writeERKSt8optionalINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE
```

Does this mean that the relevant symbol is invisible to the application trying to link to the library, or am I chasing my tail?

Does anyone have any insight or ideas that might help me fix this?

Comment: If you think you have a solution please remove it from the question and make an answer. If you only describe what you consider an unsatisfactory solution (good thing for reference in a question) please be more explicit about it. Your edit summary says "solved", so I guess the first is the case. Your choice however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, though I still don't know why the behavior changed the way it did with the addition of a pair of parameters to a function ... I can only imagine that the library defining the types sets the visibility to hidden or something...

For posterity, for a library that doesn't need to exist outside GCC/Clang, can append this after the namespace name
`__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))`
or
can prepend  `#pragma GCC visibility push(default)` and postpend `#pragma GCC visibility pop` this for larger blocks where you need everything visible. (I effectively boxed in all of my include files with this ... probably crude, but was effective)